# Using Python with usaspending.gov API to submit an advanced filtered query criteria and access data using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, api

I'm a beginner programmer and I'm using the following python code to access usaspending.gov data. I would like to use their available API instead to avoid having to download a zipped file and then opening it using pandas to perform a data analysis. Would anyone be able to direct me on how to use the website's API to enter advanced query parameters and then access the data with pandas without having to download their zipped file? If you can provide a code snippet with an example of an extracted query with random parameters, I'd appreciate that!

Here's the link to their API advanced query: https://www.usaspending.gov/search
And here's the link to their API endpoints: https://api.usaspending.gov/docs/endpoints

Lastly, here's the current code, I'm using:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time

driver webdriver.Chrome (r"C:\Users\m\Desktop\chromedriver.exe") driver.get("https://www.usaspending.gov/search/?hash=54611813edefaca2978066b4b4620302")

time.sleep (1)

download driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='label' ]").click() download driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@title='Award']").click()
download driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@title='Everything']").click()
```

Comment: Read the doc: https://api.usaspending.gov/docs/ and use `requests` package to get  data.

Answer (score 2):

A simple case to start:

```
import pandas as pd
import requests

url = "https://api.usaspending.gov"
endpoint = "/api/v2/financial_balances/agencies"
payload = {"funding_agency_id": 775, "fiscal_year": 2017}

response = requests.get(f"{url}{endpoint}", params=payload)
data = response.json()

df = pd.DataFrame(data["results"])
```

```
>>> df
  budget_authority_amount obligated_amount   outlay_amount
0         101176701717.16   82181642249.31  75144058726.11
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this! I'm starting to get the hang of it. But at this point, I'm trying to pull the entire data rows and fields they have for a specific awarding organization. The endpoints don't seem to have an option to use a GET method to extract such info. But I see this endpoint to use a hash value of a filtered query to extract the data: /api/v2/references/hash/. Do you happen to know how can I use a POST method with this endpoint to perform that for a specific organization? The documentation for the endpoint is right here: /api/v2/references/hash/